# MySQL: query with criterion IS NOT NULL is returning fields with NULL

Tags: mysql

I ran the query in the screenshot below, but no data was supposed to be returned because `element_35` contains `null`. How do I fix this issue? The data type of `element_35` is `DATE`.

I also tried `AND element_35 <> '' AND element_35 <> '(null)'` but the row below was still returned.

[image]

Comment: IS NOT NULL will *not* match values that are null. It is likely the data is the string `'(null)'`. Try: `.. AND element_35 <> '(null)'`.

Comment: I just tried it now. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is some kind of value in `element_35`, but my Java application converts that value to `null`.

[image]

I figured out how to filter out the data. One way is to use a bogus value for the criterion, e.g. `WHERE element_35 > '1970-01-01'`.